# KendoGrid - Adding & Removing the extra row is DUPLICATING the detailrows

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I wish to add one extra row into the detailRow to show a full description above the rows.

But for some reason, when i click the expand or collapse indicator in the master row, it is generating the unwanted duplicate detail rows. Please suggest how to fix this issue. I am not sure, where i am getting wrong or missing something. Although, both functions are working fine in terms of adding & removing the extra row element. But not sure, why the detail rows are getting added again and again.

During debugging in firebug, i found that function "detailInitfunc" gets the hit every time i click the expand or collapse icons. And i guess this creates the multiple detail rows on every action.

Kendo UI dojo link - [dojo.telerik.com/@maximus392/iSiyU](http://dojo.telerik.com/@maximus392/iSiyU)

Both functions are present in the end of this post.

```
  $("#gridAudit").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: partnergroups,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    PartnerGroupID : {type: "number"},
                                    PartnerName: { type: "string" },
                                    PartnerDescription: { type: "string" },
                                    AcquisitionPrice: { type: "number" }

                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 10,
                        sort: { field: "PartnerName", dir: "asc" }
                    },
                    height: 250,                    
                    scrollable: true,                    
                    sortable: true,
                    filterable: true,                       
                    detailInit: detailInitfunc,
                    detailCollapse: detailCollapsefunc,
                    detailExpand: detailExpandfunc,
                    pageable: {
                        input: true,
                        numeric: true
                    },
                    columns: [
                        { field: "PartnerName", title: "Partner Name", width: "150px" },
                        { field: "PartnerDescription", title: "Partner Desc", width: "150px" },
                        { field: "Units", title: "Units", format:"{0:##,#;(##,#)}", width: "80px" },
                        { field: "AcquisitionPrice", title: "Acquisition Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" }
                    ]
                }); //E.O. "kendoGrid" initialization



  function detailCollapsefunc(e) { $(e.masterRow).parent().find(".trchd").remove();                                
   }

  function detailExpandfunc(e) {          
       $("<tr class='trchd' style='text-align:center;'><td colspan='10'><b>Group History</b></td></tr>").insertBefore(e.detailRow);                
   }

  function detailInitfunc(e) {
                $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: childgroups,
                        filter: { field: "PartnerGroupID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.PartnerGroupID }
                    },
                    scrollable: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    pageable: false,
                    columns: [
                        { field: "PartnerName", title: "Partner Name", width: "150px" },
                        { field: "PartnerDescription", title: "Partner Desc", width: "150px" },
                        { field: "Units", title: "Units", format: "{0:##,#;(##,#)}", width: "80px" },
                        { field: "AcquisitionPrice", title: "Acquisition Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" }       
                    ]                 
                });
            }  //E.O. "detailInitfunc"
```

[image: Duplicate detail rows]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what is creating that issue. The `detailInit` should be called *once*, since it hadles the [*initialization*](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-detailInit) of the child grid. [Check this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IcAxE/2) out, and check your console to see that the `e` is logged only once per row. Or it should be at least. Furthermore, I can't see where you add an extra row, I see only the row *Group History* but it isn't in your screenshot, so I think you're not talking about it, right ?

Comment: I'll attach a new screenshot and do some test.

Comment: The new row is added under the detailExpandfunc function.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot

Comment: In the expand event you add the row to the `e.detailRow` but in the collapse you perform a search at `e.masterRow`'s parent. They are the same ? Did `$(e.masterRow).parent().find(".trchd")` returns any element? It seems that it doesn't returns it, so it is being kept and each expand you add one more. I'm not sure. Can you provide a demo at http://dojo.telerik.com/ with the issue ?

Comment: Please find the sample. It is easy to reproduce the issue. Just click expand couple of times... http://dojo.telerik.com/@maximus392/iSiyU

Comment: New row is getting inserted & deleted correctly. But the detail rows is getting added every time..

Comment: Yep, now I can see it. It seems to be a bug to me. I say it because if you remove the `detailExpand` and `detailCollapse` events, the `detailInit` works as expected. It is like if the fact you add a row mess up the default behaviour. Try posting this issue to kendo forum to see what they have to say.

Comment: I guess there could be some internal observable behavior in the control. And the addition of new row might have trigger the detailInit event call again.. I am not sure..

Comment: Sure, that is why I have proposed you to post on kendo forums, they will tell if this is an expected behaviour or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll send the post to the forum.