# KendoGrid - Hide the detail column with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using a KendoGrid control for laying down the hierarchical data. But i want to hide one of the columns in the detail or child table dynamically with the condition. The child grid is build up with the help of detailInit function of the main grid. Please advise or suggest, how to hide the child table col on the fly.

```
$(function () {
    $("#gridAudit").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: partnergroups,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        PartnerGroupID : {type: "number"},
                        PartnerName: { type: "string" },
                        OperationType: { type: "string" },
                        HasHistory: { type: "boolean" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            sort: { field: "PartnerName", dir: "asc" }
        },
        height: 250,                    
        scrollable: true,                    
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,                        
        detailInit: detailInitfunc,
        pageable: {
            input: true,
            numeric: true
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "PartnerName", title: "Partner Name", width: "150px" },
            { field: "OperationType", title: "Status", width: "80px" }
        ]
    }); //E.O. "kendoGrid" initialization   

});     //E.O. "DomReady"


function detailInitfunc(e) {
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: childgroups,
            filter: { field: "PartnerGroupID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.PartnerGroupID }
        },
        scrollable: false,
        sortable: false,
        pageable: false,
        columns: [
            { field: "PartnerName", title: "Partner Name", width: "150px" },
            { field: "OperationType", title: "Status", width: "80px" },
            { field: "Revert", title: "Action", width: "80px", template: '<i class="fa fa-floppy-o fontIcon" onclick="revertData(#=HistoryID#);" title="Revert the record"></i> ' }
        ]
    });
}  //E.O. "detailInitfunc"
```

I want to hide the Revert column in the child table based on the value of the OperationType field coming from the main table.

Please suggest the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished by managing the `columns` property in the creation of the detail grid. The information you already have, and it comes with `e.data`(shortened snippet):

```
var columns = [
    { field: "PartnerName", title: "Partner Name", width: "150px" },
    { field: "OperationType", title: "Status", width: "80px" }
];

if (e.data.OperationType == "Type #1") {
    columns.push({ field: "Revert", title: "Action", width: "80px", template: '<i class="fa fa-floppy-o fontIcon" onclick="revertData(#=HistoryID#);" title="Revert the record"></i> ' });
}

$("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    columns: columns
});
```

[Working Demo with Full Code](http://dojo.telerik.com/Ivivu)

Or even simple, to set the column's `hidden` property(shortened snippet):

```
var hidden = false;

if (e.data.OperationType == "Type #1") {
    hidden = true;
}

$("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    columns: [{ field: "Revert", title: "Action", width: "80px", template: '<i class="fa fa-floppy-o fontIcon" onclick="revertData(#=HistoryID#);" title="Revert the record"></i> ', hidden: hidden }]
});
```

[Working Demo with Full Code](http://dojo.telerik.com/IcAxE)

Comment: Thanks, Let me try it quickly.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Works :-)

Comment: I am new to this KendoGrid framework. Could you please help me in my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801470/kendogrid-adding-removing-the-extra-row-is-duplicating-the-detailrows

Comment: @Karan I'm glad it helped. I will take a look at the other question.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown i need your help. could you pls tell how to restrict kendo grid properties based on datasource.? i want to remove 'resize' property when there is no data in data source. how to achieve this conditionally ?

Comment: @worstCoder just use [`setOptions`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/setoptions) to change it whenever it has data or not, check [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/iZozUDIC). I recomend you to use it on [`dataBound`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound).

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown  . i dont understand this !grid.options.resizable .could be pls give solution directly to my issue?

Comment: @worstCoder that is the options you will change.. change to true or false depending on your needs..

Comment: what i tried is. if(this.gridkendo.DataSource.length == 0){  this.kendoCommand.resize =  false }

Comment: @worstCoder `grid.dataSource.data().length` to check the data length.

Comment: i dont know why this is not working . if (grid.dataSource.data().length == 0){
                    this.kendocommand.resize = false;
                    console.log("its 0, so false")
                } else {
                   this.kendocommand.resize = true;
                   console.log("it has records, so true")
                } the condition perfectly returns value but dont know why the column property has not removed

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown thanks man.. setOption did the magic.. finally my issue got fixed